# Open a file with gedit over ssh

Tags: permissions, ssh, sudo, gedit, x11-forwarding

I am trying to display a file with gedit, from my home, when connected to ssh in a machine of my uni. However, something is wrong with permissions.

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ ssh -X user@machine.gr
directory>gedit main.c 

** (gedit:22737): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-N7h3SJlvli: Connection refused
^C
directory>sudo gedit main.c
[sudo] password for user: 
user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Is there any hope?

From Windows I have winScp installed and I simply open the file with my editor there...

Comment: I don't think that warning should be fatal: you might try with `gedit -s` (standalone mode) though. Can you run a simple X client such as `xeyes` remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should just wait for the editor to open, just like steeldriver said.